# This app is not available for any of your devices Playstore App Issue

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-10.0, android-compatibility

I have created a barcode reader application with the following Permissions in Android Manifest. When First time my application is live in playstore it showing **"This app is not available for any of your devices"**. But i have used the same device to debug then there was not issues.

**Android Manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.compan.barcode.scanner"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this exact issue right now. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: has this issue resolved?

Comment: Resolved. Please check my own answer. Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me but I have the same problem with my wearable app, but on the documentation  it states that the line which is similar to the one you removed is mandatory. Meaning you have to add it when publishing a wearable app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i could resolve the issue by removing the following line from manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
```

This permission was added without my knowledge (may be auto imported)